# Crash-course help in receiving data in Java, TCP/IP

Tags: sockets, tcp, stream, ip

I am having problems in receiving a simple String data type, the data is being sent from the IP 10.10.11.5 over port 1180 (Labview is sending the packet). When I try this code, I get an connection error.
Error Msg:

```
 java.io.IOException: ConnectException: connect refused
 in virtual method #12 of com.sun.squawk.platform.posix.GCFSocketsImpl(bci=233)
 at com.sun.squawk.io.j2me.socket.Protocol.open(bci=104)
 in static method #4 of javax.microedition.io.Connector(bci=125)
 at javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(231)
 at javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(193)
 at javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(177)
 atedu.wpi.first.wpilibj.templates.RobotTemplate.robotInit(RobotTemplate.java:33)
 at edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.IterativeRobot.startCompetition(IterativeRobot.java:74)
 at edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.RobotBase.startApp(RobotBase.java:156)
 in virtual method #10 of javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet(bci=17)
 at javax.microedition.midlet.MIDletTunnelImpl.callStartApp(64)
 at com.sun.squawk.imp.MIDletMainWrapper.main(110)
 in virtual method #95 of com.sun.squawk.Klass(bci=25)
 at com.sun.squawk.Isolate.run(1506)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(231)
 in virtual method #47 of com.sun.squawk.VMThread(bci=42)
 in static method #3 of com.sun.squawk.VM(bci=6)
```

Thanks in advance for tips and help!

```
SocketConnection socketConnect;
InputStream myInputStream;
Datagram datagram;
DatagramConnection dataConnect;
String message;
DataInputStream stream;

public void robotInit() {

    message = null;
    try {
    socketConnect = (SocketConnection) Connector.open("socket://10.10.11.5:1180");
    myInputStream = socketConnect.openInputStream();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

EDIT: 
Our setup is simple, yet complicated. The code you see is put onto a cRIO, it is connected to our laptop via Ethernet cable. On the Labtop we have Labview generating packets of data which we are sending over port 1180 to the IP of 10.10.11.2 (The IP of the cRIO).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a "programming error" - I'm almost certain the problem is "network configuration".

Check for any firewalls between your listener (server) program and the client.

Check for Windows firewall especially.

If you're going over a company router, you might have to get your site's network administrator involved to "punch a hole" for you :)

Comment: "Connection refused" is the problem.  It might mean there's nobody listening on port 1180 on the host you're trying to connect to; it might mean somebody's blocking that port.  Q: Do you have a process listening on port 1180?  Q: If "yes", can you connect locally, on the same host?  Q: Are there any firewalls or routers between 10.10.11.2 and 10.10.11.5?  Q: Are there any software firewalls (like Windows firewall and/or A/V software) running on either host?

Comment: Firewalls have been disabled. Internet is disabled all it is are the two wired together.
We have no process listening

Comment: One detail is that the error happens almost immediately after compiling.

Comment: Focus on "connection refused".  You can test with a non-Java client, you can test with "telnet HOSTNAME PORT#".  You can even view the TCP/IP packets with Wireshark: http://www.wireshark.org/.  Q: Can the two hosts "ping" each other?  If not - you don't have networking, and they can't communicate.  Q: Is there any process listening on port 1180?  If not, then there's obviously nobody for the client to "connect" to.